# How secure is my MLab Shared Cluster MongoDB database?

Tags: encryption, tls, firewalls, mongodb

I have deployed a Meteor application to Meteor Galaxy. I've also created an Mlab.com Shared Cluster MongoDB. [Link to the plan features](https://mlab.com/plans/).

My application has an SSL certificate installed on the domain.

I'm still learning about security so I am looking for some answers to these questions:

1) Is the shared cluster database available from the open internet?

2) Is communication from a shared cluster database to the application encrypted?

If number 2 is no, why is the Shared Cluster plan even offered? Surely not having communication encrypted makes no sense whatsoever?

Comment: Hi, I understand that but I was hoping someone who is familiar with the MongoLab.com Shared Cluster would know if it even supports encryption-in-flight.

I've read the FAQ's and Docs but I am slightly overwhelmed and just can't quite work out if their shared cluster supports this stuff

Comment: Oh, I see, you are asking if it is possible.  I read it as wanting to know if your particular instance was.  That makes more sense and is answerable.  I'm retracting my close vote.

Comment: These seem like great questions (and valid concerns) to discuss with MLab support. According to the plan details you referenced the Shared Cluster plan does not include SSL support for database connections, custom firewall rules, or private networking with AWS peering. It appears that the only security measure in the Shared plan is user authentication (!).

Comment: The MongoDB documentation has a helpful [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist/) with information on recommended security measures. If your app is communicating with a hosted DB over the public internet you definitely want auth, SSL, and firewall measures at a minimum.

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I now realise that the Shared Cluster doesn't have the ssecurity I need, so I am going to switch over to something else. Unfortunately the next plan up from Shared Cluster is $180/m which seems like a huge jump, so I think I'll need to switch providers.